# Visual Studio Code Java compile multiple classes and import jar-s?

Tags: java, visual-studio, class, jar, visual-studio-code

I am switching from NetBeans to VS Code Java on Linux and I am unable to run or build my projects. I get `error: cannot find symbol` for every class declaration or external package usage.

- How do I build all the `.java` classes in a project folder, not just the currently opened one?
- How can I import `.jar` in VS code?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes. I use IntelliJ.